# onCreateContextMenu Throws Error on API 15 & 16 only

Tags: android

I'm having an issue with the onCreateContextMenu throwing a error only on API 15 & 16. It works perfectly fine on every other API from API 8 to API 17 (my min and max targets).

I did my best to try and solve this issue on my own by searching through Google, but after about a week I've became desperate enough to plead for help from the wonderful stack overflow community.

**The onCreateContextMenu method**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    Log.i(TAG, "Create context menu");

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_my_time_zone, menu);

    Log.i(TAG, "Context menu created.");
}
```

**The Containing Class**

```
public class MyTimeZoneTActivity extends ListActivity {
    // I can post the code for the Class if required.
}
```

**The Exception**

```
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.creativitality.labs.timezoneswidget.MyTimeZonesActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Application
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.Window.getCompatInfo(Window.java:481)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.<init>(Window.java:491)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:477)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.Window.setWindowManager(Window.java:460)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:163)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.create(AlertDialog.java:913)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.show(MenuDialogHelper.java:79)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:88)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2201)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:612)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2926)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2871)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-14 09:38:20.828: E/AndroidRuntime(10912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**Anything else I can provide?**

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide to help solve this issue.

Thank you all in advance!

---

### Additional Code (as requested)

**ListActivity**

```
public class MyTimeZonesActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Define application context
    private Context applicationContext;

    //LIST OF ARRAY STRINGS WHICH WILL SERVE AS LIST ITEMS
    List<TimeZoneData> timeZoneData = null;

    //DEFINING STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE DATA OF LISTVIEW
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TimeZoneAdaptor timezoneAdaptor = null;

    public static final int INSTRUCTIONS_CODE = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "MyTimeZonesActivity";

    SharedPreferences sharedPref;
    SharedPreferencesHelper sharedPreferencesHelper;

    TimeZonesApplication timeZonesApplication;

    public Context getApplicationContext(){
        return applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Log.i(TAG, "My Time Zone Activity - onCreate called.");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        // Get Application Globals
        timeZonesApplication = (TimeZonesApplication)getApplicationContext();

        // Set application context
        applicationContext = this;

        // Populate time zone data
        timeZoneData = new ArrayList<TimeZoneData>();
        getStoredTimeZonesData(); // Populates timeZoneData object with stored time zone data

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_time_zones);
        timezoneAdaptor = new TimeZoneAdaptor(this, R.layout.timezone_view_mine, timeZoneData);
        setListAdapter(timezoneAdaptor);

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    }
```

**ArrayAdapter**

```
public class TimeZoneAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<TimeZoneData> {
    private String TAG = "TimeZoneAdaptor";
    //private ArrayList<TimeZoneData> mOrigionalValues;
    private List<TimeZoneData> mObjects;

    public TimeZoneAdaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<TimeZoneData> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.mObjects = objects;
        //this.mOrigionalValues = new ArrayList<TimeZoneData>(objects);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ((null != mObjects) ? mObjects.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public TimeZoneData getItem(int position) {
        return ((null != mObjects) ? mObjects.get(position) : null);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void add(TimeZoneData timeZone)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Add time zone: " + timeZone.id);
        mObjects.add(timeZone);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void remove(int position){
        Log.i(TAG, "Remove object from adapter at position: " + position);
        mObjects.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if (null == view) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) MyTimeZonesActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.timezone_view_mine, null);
        }

        TimeZoneData data = mObjects.get(position);

        if (null != data) {
            TextView textCountry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timezone_country);
            TextView textName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timezone_name);
            TextView textTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timezone_time);

            textCountry.setText(data.country.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()));
            textName.setText(data.city);
            textTime.setText(data.time);

            //view.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position)); // NOT REQUIRED as we are setting in on activity level
        }

        return view;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Paste some more code, especially of your ListView and anapter and how you are creating an adapter.

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherlock or native ActionBar?

Comment: There is no action bar in use, as far as I know. Actually, I'm pretty sure I'm only using the menu and contextMenu.

Comment: I've posted some more code as requested: **ListActivity Class** & **Custom Array Adapter**

Comment: @MichałZ. The line that is throwing the error seems to be: **inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_my_time_zone, menu);**. If I comment that out, the rest of the code runs ok. No menu is created, but no error is thrown either.

Comment: @MichałZ. I've also commented out the **inflater.inflate()** line and attempted to create the menu items programatically using **menu.setHeaderTitle("Time Zone Actions");** & **menu.add(0, Menu.FIRST, 0, getString(R.string.delete));** but again it throws the same error at **menu.add()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

The issue was because I overwrote an existing API method **getApplicationContext()** without being aware of it.

The method in question that was causing all my headaches was this:

```
public Context getApplicationContext(){
    return applicationContext;
}
```

I found this bit of code while I was searching up better ways of passing context to my methods. It turns out you shouldn't use any code until you full understand it!

Hope that someone else finds this answer useful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you are somehow creating a widget using an `Application` instead of an `Activity`, such as by blindly using `getApplicationContext()` someplace. When Android goes to show the context menu, it tries to get the activity associated with the widget, runs into an `Application` instead, and crashes.

Comment: I will try and hunt down the possible problem and see if that is the issue.

In the mean time, do you have any idea why would my code workfor API's: 8-14 & 17, but not for 15 & 16?

Comment: @Igor: Probably due to changes in the internal implementation. Android is not a static code base.

Comment: The Activity calling the contextMenu is not a widget provider. The activity is used to configure the widget.

I had other similar issues that appeared only in API 15 & 16, throwing an error **cannot be cast to android.app.Application** that were caused by **static** deceleration of some variables.

Any idea of what I could do to get closer to the root of this problem?

Comment: You were on the right track with your answer. The **getApplicationContext()** was the culprit. However, it wasn't being blindly used, I declared it again without properly extending the method.